# Tableau fails to properly parse Number fields with the scentific notation

Tags: csv, tableau-api, scientific-notation

I have a CSV text file that contains a column with large numbers. Some numbers in this column are presented in the scientific notation. Neither the "Number (whole)" nor the "Number (decimal)" type are able to properly parse the data. That is, Tableau simply ignores the cells with such numbers.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try this suggestion on [Tableau's forum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEpeLatYHRAhUKxVQKHR0lA4gQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.tableau.com%2Fthread%2F128914&usg=AFQjCNFvSwMW5ReIcLV-rkwsIuotY57BFA&sig2=YPVQWrMBBoBUgG4ErxAIAg). I haven't run into this problem so I can't vouch for whether that solution works or not.

Comment: The schematic.ini solution may be out of date. Tableau stopped using ms jet long ago. I would contact support and you could preprocessing the file with Python or even excel to convert the format

Comment: It is quite important to know the exact format of the problematic column. How does the CSV file look in a text editor? Are all the numbers in that column in the same format?